# CoffeeScript String Comparison

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, is there a way to simplify the following:

```
if(value === "something" || value === "else" || value === "wow"){}
```

I've tried:

```
if value is "something" or "else" or "wow"
```

But this produces the literal output of this:

```
if(value === "something" || "else" || "wow){}
```

**Is there a way to check if a string is one of multiple values (OR or AND) in CoffeeScript?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you probably want

```
if value in ['something', 'else', 'wow']
```