# Really basic javascript, checking a condition using || (or)

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript, and trying to learn using lynda.com.

I'm currently playing around with the if statement.

**The code in question:**

```
var value = prompt("1 or 2?");

if ( value == 1 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 1.");
} 

if ( value == 2 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 2.");
}   

if ( value != (1 || 2) ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

This is what i want to happen: If the number is NOT 1 or 2, i want JS to execute this piece of code:

```
 if ( value != (1 || 2) ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

Apparently this is not the correct way to write it out, and i've tried writing it a bunch of different ways. Can someone show me the correct way, possibly using the else statement?

Comment: Though I don't use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) myself, you can do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15508553/586621): `if value not in [1, 2] then` if you ever decide to venture into the preprocessor route some day.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( value != 1 && value != 2) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

If you write `value != (1||2)`, the `(1||2)` will get first evaluated to `1` and then  compared to `value`, so you effectively wrote:

```
if ( value != 1 ) { [...] }.
```

This is because the `()` have a higher predence than `!=`. You can also read [this explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) about ***operator predence*** which gives more details.

Comment: I believe the OP effectively wrote if(value != 1)

Comment: No. It would get evaluated to `1`.

Comment: Press F12 and enter `(1||2)` - it will return 1

Comment: Yes, @TobSpr - do that and you'll see the result is 1

Answer (score 3):

1

```
if ( value != 1 && value !=2 ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

2

```
 if ( !(value == 1 || value ==2) ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

3

```
if ( value == 1 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 1.");
} 
else if ( value == 2 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 2.");
}   
else {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to write this statement would be as follow:

```
if ( value == 1 )
{
  alert("1");
}
else if ( value == 2 )
{
  alert("2");
}
else
{
  alert("no 1 or 2");
}
```

The if statement that you are messing on is (1 || 2)
What will happen is it will do a Boolean test and return 1.
it should look like this

```
if ( value !== 1 && value !== 2 )
{
  alert("no 1 or 2");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, the best is to separate into two NOT statements,and evaluate both:

```
if ( value != 1 && value != 2) ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

However, you could also use the `if`, `else if`, `else` pattern to cover yourself against all other inputs (letters, punctuation, whitespace, etc).  The `else` acts as a catch-all at the end:

```
var value = prompt("1 or 2?");

if ( value == 1 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 1.");
} 

else if ( value == 2 ) {
    alert("You have chosen 2.");
}   

else {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have tried writing

```
if(value != 1 && value != 2)
```

Comment: Tell me a `value` that doesn't pass this condition.

Comment: the value would be 1 and the condition is not meet

Comment: @Saint: He's changed `||` to `&&` now.

Comment: did not notice... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Inline statements like: `(1 || 2)` only evaluate the right hand side of the `||` if the left hand side is false-y. So what your statement actually is saying is:

```
if ( value != 1 )
```

Because `1` evaluates to true.

As most others have pointed out, what you actually want to do is:

```
if ( value != 1 && value != 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is incorrect. You have to do in this way

```
if ( value != 1 && value != 2) ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

the `(1||2)` statement is evaluated as `1` so you are testing if `value != 1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like

```
if ( value != 1 && value != 2 ) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

OR

```
if (!(value == 1 || value == 2)) {
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if ( value != (1 || 2) )
```

What ths is doing is checking if "value" is not equal to (1 OR 2), where (1 OR 2) is evaluated first, because it's in the brackets. (1 OR 2) evaluates to 1, since 1 is truthy in javascript. What your code is actually doing is checking if your value is not equal to 1.

What you actually want to do is check if your value is !=1 and that your value is !=2. You do that like this:

```
if (value !=1 && value !=2) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: No problem, just fixed your `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch as follows

```
switch(value) {
  case 1:
    alert("You have chosen 1.");
    break;
  case 2:
    alert("You have chosen 2.");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Invalid number. Try again.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a clause.  You can just use:

```
else{
}
```